# Scope of negation

Tags: meaning-in-context, negation

**Dann isst er zu Mittag nicht daheim, sondern jausnet mit seinen Freunden in der Schule.**

I came across this sentence. And I have 2 possible meanings of it:

1. He doesn't have lunch at home but instead he has a snack at school with his friends.
2. He has lunch but not at home and apart of that has a snack at school with his friends.

What I really don't understand is the meaning of "**nicht**". Does it affect "daheim" or the verb?

This is the context:

> Ein Tag mit Robert
>
> Robert ist zwölf Jahre alt und wohnt zusammen mit seinen Eltern und drei Geschwistern in Wien, der Hauptstadt von Österreich.
> An Schultagen weckt ihn seine Mutter um Viertel nach sechs. Er steht gleich auf und geht dann ins Badezimmer, duscht und putzt seinen Zähne. Danach zieht er sich an. Gemeinsam mit seiner Familie frühstückt Robert. Meistens isst er ein Müsli und trinkt dazu einen Früchtetee. Bevor er losgeht, putzt er seine Zähne noch einmal.
> Schnell geht Robert dann mit zwei seiner Geschwister zur U-Bahn-Station. Bis zur Schule muss er drei Stationen weit fahren und noch ein kleines Stück zu Fuß gehen. Der Unterricht beginnt um Dreiviertel acht und endet fast jeden Tag um ein Uhr. Zweimal in der Woche hat Robert auch am Nachmittag Unterricht. Dann isst er zu Mittag nicht daheim, sondern jausnet mit seinen Freunden in der Schule.
> Zu Hause gibt es gegen ein Uhr das Mittagessen. Dabei erzählen die Kinder ihrer Mutter die Erlebnisse des Tages. Robert macht die Aufgaben für den nächsten Tag.
> Ab und zu Spielt er ein Computerspiel oder übt ein wenig auf der Gitarre.
> Gegen halb sieben isst die Familie zu Abend. Danach hört Robert Musik, liest seine Jugendzeitschriften oder spielt mit seinen Geschwistern.
> Gegen halb zehn geht er ins Bett, vorher badet er noch und putzt seine Zähne.

Comment: You cannot translate "Mittagessen" with "dinner", and this could be the cause of your problem. Mittagessen is always around noon, and many (most?) children in Austria eat that meal at home, and then go back to school. A "dinner" as in Englisch is  in the afternoon,

Comment: @Beta So, could you explain how to tranlate "zu Mittag" at least in this context, please?

Comment: @Beta: amadeusamadeus edited it to "lunch" - I think the assumption is, that this was just a minor translation thing. @ Ruslan Mukhanov: depending of your view on that, you might edit "the error" back into your question if dinner was by purpose.

Comment: @RuslanMukhanov *zu Mittag essen* ('eating at noon') always means *to have lunch*. *Zu Abend essen* ('eating in the evening') means *to have dinner*. These two expressions are fixed. In Germany, Austria and Switzerland, lunch usually is the main family meal of the day since schools used to end around 1 o'clock (now there often is day-care afterwards). See also the following sentences: "Zu Hause gibt es gegen ein Uhr das Mittagessen. Dabei erzählen die Kinder ihrer Mutter die Erlebnisse des Tages."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption (1) is correct. In English, you could put it very similarly like this:

> Then he has lunch, though **not at home**, but by taking a snack with his friends at school.

Here, *not at home* has the exact same meaning as the literal translation *nicht daheim* in the original sentence.

Your assumption (2), however, is not a possible meaning here because *sondern* means *instead*, not *apart from that*. If you wanted to say *apart from that*, the sentence had to be like *Er isst zu Mittag nicht daheim; **außerdem** jausnet er mit seinen Freunden in der Schule.*

Answer (score 1):

The word **nicht** means for home (**daheim**). Then he doesn’t have lunch at home, he eat with his friends in the school (**jausnet mit seinen Freunden in der Schule**).
So the word **nicht** is not mean to the verb, but for eating at home.

The sentence we can also write as: **“Dann isst er nicht zuhause, sondern jausnet mit den Freunden in der Schule.“**

Answer (score 1):

Negationen betreffen die Semantik und in der Semantik ist der Kontext König.

Im Deutschen ist man sehr frei, wo man das *nicht* in einer Aussage platziert.

- Er isst zu Mittag nicht daheim.
- Er isst nicht zu Mittag daheim.

Negiert wird nicht das folgende Wort, denn Worte kann man nicht negieren. "Nicht daheim" ist keine Aussage und "nicht zu Mittag" auch nicht. Man kann nur Aussagen negieren.

- Er isst zu Mittag nicht daheim, sondern abends.
- Er isst zu Mittag nicht daheim, sondern auswärts.
- Er isst nicht zu Mittag daheim, sondern zu Abend.
- Er isst nicht zu Mittag daheim, sondern auswärts.
- Er isst zu Mittag nicht daheim, sondern er fastet.
- Er isst nicht zu Mittag daheim, sondern er fastet.

Das *nicht* negiert die Aussage die aus 4 Merkmalen besteht: Das Subjekt *er* tut etwas, nämlich *essen*, und zwar - jetzt wird es kompliziert: *zur Mittagszeit/eine Mittagsmahlzeit* - am Ort: *daheim*.

Erst die dem *sondern* folgende Alternative verdeutlicht, worauf der Fokus liegt.

Hier haben wir folgende Alternative:

> sondern jausnet mit seinen Freunden in der Schule.

Wir haben 3 Änderungen. Bislang war nur von ihm die Rede, jetzt geht es auch um seine Freunde. Wahrscheinlich kommen diese nicht zum Frühstück zu seinem Zuhause (Alltagswissen). Er ist nicht mehr zu Mittag, sondern jausnet. Das ist üblicherweise eine andere Kategorie von Essen, keine umfangreiche, warme Mahlzeit sondern ein Imbiss, vielleicht eine Stulle, eine Brotzeit, e Schmier, ein Sandwich, aber wohl auch um die Mittagszeit. Und es findet in der Schule statt.

Aber ohne den Inhalt dessen, was nach dem sondern kommt, wüssten wir nur dass er nicht zu Mittag daheim ist. Zu Abend ist er wohl schon daheim. In der Schule isst er auch mittags. Es ist der ganze Teilsatz, die Aussage in ihrer vollen Pracht, die negiert wird.

> Er besitzt keine rote Hose, sondern

- eine blaue.
- einen roten Rock.
- trägt die seiner Schwester.
- lebt seit seiner Geburt nackt im Dschungel, wo man weder roten Fabstoff, noch Hosen und auch keinen Besitz kennt.

Statt *keine* zu verwenden könnte man den Satz auch umstellen:

> Eine rote Hose besitzt er nicht, sondern

- eine blaue.
- einen roten Rock.
- trägt die seiner Schwester.
- lebt seit seiner Geburt nackt im Dschungel, wo man weder roten Fabstoff, noch Hosen und auch keinen Besitz kennt.

> Das rote Auto besitzt nicht er sondern

- die Bank.

Hier wird auch offen gelassen, ob er ein blaues Auto besitzt, ein rotes Fahrrad und es riecht auch sehr danach, dass er das rote Auto fährt. Aber man kann die Aussage nicht aufsplitten in Teile, die negiert werden und andere, die nicht negiert werden. Die Konstruktion mit dem *nicht* vor *er* drängt aber hier auf einen anderen Besitzer hinter dem *sondern*. Ähnlich wäre es beim Ausgangssatz:

- Nicht er isst zu Mittag daheim, sondern sein Vater.